# Equivalent model - Reuss/Voigt

Tags: education, continuum-mechanics

I'm wondering if is possible to simplify a model consists of three components in the following way when I have to apply Reuss and Voigt models:

[image]

Thank you very much for your willingness.

Comment: What is/are Reuss and Voigt models? What is the image you've attached?

Comment: Hello @KyleKanos here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_mixtures you can find more details (rule of mixtures and inverse rule of mixtures)...and here https://www.doitpoms.ac.uk/tlplib/fibre_composites/stiffness.php